# Jenkins giving error while cloning from gitHub

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am new to `Jenkins`, I am getting following error while cloning repository from `GitHub`.

I tried to search all relevant issues here but could find exact stacktstrace with answers.

I am trying to clone repository which requires username and password, I am providing `SSH://` repository-path in job configuration settings for my job. I have not done any .ssh related settings yet as this seems to be different problem than security issue with GIT repository.

I couldn't figure out what comment Jenkins is trying to execute, which file/directory it is not finding clueless.

**Here is my exact stack trace from Jenkins job:**

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program:  Error trying to
>   determine the git version: Error performing command:  --version
>       Assuming 1.6
>       ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'myRE' : Could not clone git@github.com:myORG/RVL.myProj.git
>       hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone git@github.com:myORG/RVL.myProj.git
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:268)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1122)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1064)
>         at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:842)
>         at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1064)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1256)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:589)
>         at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
>         at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
>         at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1502)
>         at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
>         at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>         at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
>       Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command:  clone -o RVL.myProj git@github.com:myORG/RVL.myProj.git
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myProj/workspace
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:862)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.access$000(GitAPI.java:40)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:264)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:244)
>         at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:842)
>         at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:244)
>         ... 13 more
>       **Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""**: error=2, No such file or directory
>         at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>         at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:244)
>         at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:216)
>         at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
>         at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
>         at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
>         at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:843)
>         ... 19 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
>         at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Pro

Comment: What happens if you type "git --version" at the command line on the Jenkins master? This looks like you do not have git installed.

Comment: Looks like there was problem in GIT configuration of Jenkins, gave full path of GIT instead of only "git" (suggested by jenkins)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I encountered and fixed the same problem :)

There are two way to configure the path of git:

1. On Jenkins Master

   a. Enter Jenkins System Configure (Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System )

   b. Find the Git item and Configure the git installation (specify the git path on Jenkins Master)
2. On Jenkins Slave

   a. Enter Jenkins Slave's Configure

   b. Check the "Tool Locations" Checkbox and specify the path of git on the Jenkins Slave.

In my situation, I don't have the privilege to access the Jenkins Master. So I install the git on the Jenkins Slave and add it to Jenkins Slave's Configure.

Comment: For me, the git path option was at Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug, see [JENKINS-16523](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16523) where I posted a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same issue.

I noticed the mixture of git configuration in individual jobs "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/job_name/config.xml":

```
[root@jenkins.example.com jobs]# find . -maxdepth 2 -name     config.xml|xargs grep '<gitTool>'
./job1/config.xml:    <gitTool>git</gitTool>
./job2/config.xml:    <gitTool>Default</gitTool>
./job3/config.xml:    <gitTool>git</gitTool>
./job4/config.xml:    <gitTool>Default</gitTool>
```

So I fixed the name of gitTool and restarted the Jenkins. It looks like the git configuration doesn't properly and the change of git is not propagated to all jobs.

Also be aware that the git configuration can differ in .xml file with configuration and the configuration in webface of the Jenkins!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `git --version` on either Master or Slave
2. If you do not get anything, that means Git is not installed
3. If you think Git is installed, add path of the Git executable (e.g. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd) to the `PATH` environment variable
4. Run `git --version` on either Master or Slave and make sure that you get the valid version

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue after I created a new `JOB`, fixed it correcting the slave name (with `GIT` Installed) in `Label Expression` under `Restrict where this project can be run`.

Answer (score 0):

Except for step answered by superlee, you need config your node properties for your server side, the Tool Locations if your local is windows system, refer to below screenshot:

[tool location for your server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxvAL.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could happen due to a variety of reasons.

1. You might not have git installed
2. Jenkins is not able to use the git binary
3. Permission issue.

This blog , [Jenkins Git Clone Error](https://scriptcrunch.com/git-clone-error-java-io-ioexception/), explains all the scenarios of this error and its solution.