# ERROR: Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt

Tags: git, jenkins, repository, jenkins-plugins, corrupt

I am not able to pull the code from Github through jenkins. I did try to switch the git plugins in jenkins but it didn't work. No idea what the issue is..Some pointers for this would be helpful..
 Am i missing some plugins or ami using plugins with the wrong version?

```html
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestGitCon/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestGitCon/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@37ff3f85
Using strategy: Default
ERROR: Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt.
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: usr/bin/git rev-parse --verify HEAD
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:904)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:858)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:868)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.validateRevision(GitAPI.java:326)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.hasGitRepo(GitAPI.java:125)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1005)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:986)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:986)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1142)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1265)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "usr/bin/git" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestGitCon/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:803)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:388)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:885)
 ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
 ... 24 more
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:RosettaCommons/main.git
Error trying to determine the git version: Error performing command: usr/bin/git --version
Assuming 1.6
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:RosettaCommons/main.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway.
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: usr/bin/git fetch -t git@github.com:RosettaCommons/main.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:904)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:858)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:200)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:1105)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1064)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:986)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:986)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1142)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1265)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "usr/bin/git" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestGitCon/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:803)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:388)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:885)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
 ... 23 more
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1076)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:986)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:981)
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:986)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1142)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1265)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

Answer (score 4):

My path to git executable was var/lib/jenkins. I added a slash before var/lib/jenkins, that is, /var/lib/jenkins. Also I installed "Git pull request builder" plugin. I downgraded git plugin version to 1.1.26. Now I can download the code from github through jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, locate a `/jenkins/workspace/<job name>` directory in your Jenkins slave (or server). You should either delete all files in  the workspace (***if there is no negative implication of doing so***) or delete only the `.git` directory.

Run your job again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but in my case the reason was different. Actually, I had used curl command in a shell script file and then I had to create a Docker image out it.
So to make the Docker image able to execute the curl command I had to install the Curl. And I had written the below code in Docker file

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y curl && \
```

But when I committed my code, the Jenkins build got failed with the same message **ERROR: Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt**

And the fix was that I had to add `--no-install-recommends` in the install curl command. Like this

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl && \
```

The reason for that is [Ubuntu installs recommended but not suggested packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65081/what-are-the-implications-of-no-install-recommends-apt-get-install). So, Ubuntu was trying to add some unwanted but maybe, recommended package which somehow was failing the build.

Answer (score 1):

Start checking the location you set for the git tool in the Jenkins settings (Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System).

See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16075494/6309):

> Looks like there was problem in GIT configuration of Jenkins, gave full path of GIT instead of only "`git`"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,
You should install git in your Jenkins instance (EC2)

**Ubuntu:**

> sudo apt install git -y

**Redhat:**

> sudo dnf install git -y