# Triggering a Git fetch, reset using Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant, jenkins

I have a Java package which is checked in Git (and code.amazon.com) and I have a Ant job to trigger the package. Within the Ant job, I have created a macrodef for Git and I am performing a `git fetch` and `git reset` so that I can get the latest codebase every time I am triggering the Ant job.

When I am triggering the Ant job using Eclipse, it is working. If I am running the Ant job from terminal using `ANT –buildfile my_buildfile.xml`, it is also working.

Now I have setup Jenkins on my machine and am trying to run the Ant file. Jenkins is not able to trigger the Git job in the Ant file. It is giving following error:

```
/rhel5pdi/workplace/bangshis/EpubYJConvPerfWorkspace/src/EpubYJConvPerfLinux/Jenkins_Linux_build_Global.xml:81: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/rhel5pdi/workplace/bangshis/EpubYJConvPerfWorkspace/src/EpubYJConvPerfLinux/Jenkins_Linux_build_Global.xml:99: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Part of this error might be due to the reason that, my Jenkins is not able to trigger the job as the current user of the host machine.

To solve this problem, I have tried taking the following steps:

1. Creating a global credential and using password-less account (RSA ID).
2. Logging into Jenkins using the same username as system.
3. Installing Git and Git client plugins and setting them up appropriately.

Kindly let me know if I am missing something, and if there is any way out. If my approach is not correct, I would be glad if you can share few other ideas.

Comment: How doesn't a simple git pull do the trick? Why a fetch and a reset?

Comment: Oleg!! I have added the ERROR. It doesnt matter if i do a GIT pull or fetch. I am not able to invoke any GIT command is the real issue.

Comment: @Shubhankar Raj can you run git from the terminal on your jenkins machine?

Comment: @OlegPavliv : Yes.. I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dr.Bokko is correct...and I should thank him for guiding in the right direction. I am trying to give the complete answer. There are three factors based upon which we can do the setup of GIT with JENKINS.

- 1st Factor: To access GIT repository, if it is a public repository, then user credentials would not be required. But for access restricted GIT repositories, we need to make sure that proper credentials are passed. Git and Git Client plugins need to be installed for Jenkins to understand GIT operations.
- 2nd Factor: Before running the script, add a build step and export all the libraries needed as a part of the shell script.
- 3rd Factor: Finally check the System Configuration in Manage Jenkins section and check the environment variables which are considered by Jenkins. If they are not appropriate, then go to the nodes management link, and all the environment variables as KEY-VALUE pairs.

Hopefully, these steps mentioned above would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's related to the git configuration on your master (or node)

This solution should work to fix your problem:

> [Jenkins giving error while cloning from gitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202078/jenkins-giving-error-while-cloning-from-github)

Comment: Thank you very much @Dr.Bokko. But I had already figured out the problem after doing a lot of head-banging.

Answer (score 0):

The following error appears in your stacktrace:

```
Cannot run program "git": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What that means is that the git executable is either not installed or not in the command path of the process running ANT.

It's not entirely clear why you're calling GIT from ANT. Normally Jenkins would perform the checkout of the code first (using GIT) and then call ANT. I would highly recommend investigating this alternative workflow, which might require the installation of a GIT plugin for Jenkins (can't remember if this is a default plugin or not).